# Bootstrap Align One Large Image with Four Smaller Ones

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to make a webpage with Bootstrap. This is what I want it to look like:
[image]

However I am having trouble getting the pictures to align. This is what I have so far:
[image]

I tried adding no padding and no margin to my columns but that didn't seem to do the trick. Here's the HTML I have so far:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8"><img src="img/logo.png" class="img-responsive"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="margin-top:30px"></div>

  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 nopadding"> <img class="img-responsive" src="img/tagline.png"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 nopadding"> <img class="img-responsive" src="img/karen_big.png"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 nopadding"><img class="img-responsive"src="img/don_big.png"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 nopadding"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/elwood_big.png" style=""></div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 nopadding"><img class="img-responsive" src="img/michigan.png"></div>
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```

And here's the CSS I added for no padding and no margins:

```
.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

your markup should look more like this to get the correct alignment:

```
+---------+----------+
|+-------+|          |
||   |   ||          |
|+---+---||          |
||   |   ||          |
|+---+---+|          |
+----+----+-----+----+
|    |    |     |    |
+----+----+-----+----+
```

Or translated to the bootstrap grid system:

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-6'>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-6'></div>
            <div class='col-md-6'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-md-6'></div>
            <div class='col-md-6'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='col-md-6'></div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-3'></div>
    <div class='col-md-3'></div>
    <div class='col-md-3'></div>
    <div class='col-md-3'></div>
</div>
```

And an example:http://jsfiddle.net/ajx8m5k3/

Comment: Without taking credit for your answer, add `nopadding` to all but the first `col-md-*` will get the desired result. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ajx8m5k3/1/

Comment: and just `.nopadding { padding: 0; }` will do

Comment: Thank you So much!! Combining Peter and Tim's answers did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

For just this specific case, the simplest solution is to use bootstrap's `pull-right` class on the column containing the large image.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 nopadding"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 nopadding"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 nopadding pull-right"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/300"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 nopadding"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 nopadding"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MattD Are you just talking about the image not taking the full size of the container? `.img-responsive { width:100%; }` http://www.bootply.com/UcDONcBL6u

Comment: View either of those examples using Bootply's desktop and mobile view, and adjust the width of that window. Particularly from my example, it only looks correct at a certain width. When it becomes to narrow, likely when it's bellow the threshold for the medium grid classes, the four smaller images stack on top of one another.

Comment: @MattD Well, yes, I'm still using his `col-lg-*` classes. What he posted may or may not be the minimum code to recreate the issue; I am not making any assumptions about what he wants at different breakpoints. You can just change them to `col-xs-*` and it works for all sizes.

Comment: And ideally your solution should work well at all sizes unless the asker has specified that it should collapse down differently at different widths. As such I don't feel the answer is particularly good, certainly compared to the accepted one. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: That is a much better response than `Nope.`.

Answer (score 0):

you may have to scale your images to fit the containers. e.g.

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="img/karen_big.png" width="100%" height="100%">
```

Comment: You mean just changing the size of the image? I tried that, it still doesn't work.